# Richtextbox alternative for Chat application in c# winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, chat, richtextbox

I am working on a chat application project where users communicate each other via TCP/IP socket, which is working fine. People in the chat room can share files, images, and of course plain text. I am using RichTextBox to show messages and images to clients.

Observations about RichTextBox are listed below:

- RichTextBox is working very well with plain text (very fast, and robust)
- When users pasting certain number of images, later on it gets very slow and started to crash eventually.

So my question is, what is the better way to accomplish my goal here?

- What control can use instead of RichTextBox to show messages and images? (No need to be edited, just to show messages)
- I read that WPF's richtextbox is better than old WinForms Richtextbox. Is this correct in terms of performance?
- Switching to WPF is not possible in my case and I know that Winforms can host WPF elements. Is it possible to use WPF RichTextBox editor from Winform host? (Adding image, paragraphs, setting FontColors, FontTypes and etc..)

Comment: Devexpress has a RichTextBox control. Just an alternative. You may check it using trial version. [link](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/rich_editor/)

Comment: @Badiparmagi is there any free alternative? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need complete RichTextEditing in a Chat-Application? In my opinion a chat should consist of one Font-Style etc. And why for example should someone layout text as center or sth. I would simply build a Container (UserControl, Panel etc.) where you add a label or picture edit for text/pictures. So for each message you add a label and for each picture a picture-edit. So you get a flow from top to bottom like WhatsApp or other common messengers.

If you really need the complete RichTextEditing feature, I would still seperate the images from the text part and build it up as described above. Instead of labels you use many readonly richtextedits now. The images are shown in picture-edits as well.

The advantage is you don't become big and plunky richtextedits, because you seperate the images. Further you become a messageflow shown in different boxes ordered from top to bottom, where bottom is the newest. This gives you the opportunity to just show the last 10 messages for example. If the user want to see more you have to reload old posts. So you always just show 10 (or whatever you want) messages, which will keep the memory footprint small.

Further you could compress images if they are to big or just allow a fixed size. So noone slow down your chat with high resolution images.

Without thirdparty controls I don't think you have a alternative to richtext so far you need all this editing features. If you just need to show formatted stuff you could try WebBrowser-Control and convert your rtf to html. But I don't know if this is more leigthweight.

Hint: Make sure to dispose RichTextEdits, which you don't need any longer.

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.110).aspx) which describes how to host a WPF-Control in Winforms-Application. Don't think this will give you any advantage but if you want to try it out go for it ;).

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I would love to hear! 

I was thinking to switch to panels, labels and picturebox as you said, but I was not sure that it was right thing to do! 

For me, it is much easier to manipulate data using containers, panels than using old-school richtextbox.

How about the performance if I decided to use containers? Will it slow down after adding tons of labels and pictureboxes?

Comment: @Omer If you adding tons of them for sure your application get's slower by time. You should just read the last 10 messages for example. If the user scroll up or click a 'load older messages' button for example, you can read this older messages and show them too. So you application always load minimal amount of data.

Comment: Sorry English is not my mother-tongue so I may not be that clear. What I mean by tons actuall I man 10-15.. My bad.  Current chat application already does that, and loads only last days chat history.  Btw, I just tried to add 40 pictureboxes in a panel, and worked like a charm! Thank you again.

Comment: Update: To compare performance of two methods (Richtextbox vs panel), I created an app and added same amount of text and image to both panel and Rtb.. Rtb is way faster than the panel method unfortunately. Any other ideas about this issue?